# Using MySQL or MariaDB to store locations

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, mariadb

I am designing a transportation system in which I need to store location of the vehicles at least once or twice a minute. I want to find out which database is better to choose (MySql or MariaDB) for this case in terms of performance and scalability. How much it worth if I switch to NoSQL databases such as MangoDB or whatever!?

Comment: How many vehicles?  Under 1000 - no problem with either MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: What will your `SELECTs` be?  That could be important to the decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use  features provided by NoSQL you may choose MariaDB.It has  Cassandra engine and you may use [dynamic column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/) to store data as like NoSQL inside MYSQL engine.

In terms of scaling

> NoSQL’s simpler data models can make the process easier, and many have been built with scaling functionality from the start. That is a generalization, so seek expert advice if you encounter this situation

In terms of performance

> NoSQL’s simpler denormalized store allows you to retrieve all information about a specific item in a single request. There’s no need for related JOINs or complex SQL queries.

**Where you need NoSQL ?**

1. unrelated, indeterminate or evolving data requirements
2. speed and scalability is imperative

**Where you need MYSQL?**

1. logical related discrete data requirements which can be identified up-front
2. data integrity is essential

**EDIT :**

You may check [this](http://www.zdnet.com/article/rdbms-vs-nosql-how-do-you-pick/) link.He explained RDBMS vs NoSQL very well !!